# istio azure sql db external connectivity

Tags: azure, istio

I am attempting to connect an dotnet core API to a database on Azure SQL.  Everything works fine while debugging and when running without ISTIO.  As soon as I run with ISTIO, it does not work.  I try making a ServiceEntry but it is not helping.   Can you help?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: azure-sql
spec:
  hosts:
  - <servername>.database.windows.net
  addresses:
  - <ip address>
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    number: 1433
    protocol: tcp
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, and likely you already know this by now, but just in case anyone else is having this issue...

SQL Azure uses gateway redirection - (i.e. it redirects to a different machine and port, so the host and/or port may be different from the one whitelisted)

The issue: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6587 explains this better than I can.

The suggestion is to disable this gateway mode in SQL, but there may be performance implications if you do so.

I haven't seen any other way to get around this short of allow all outbound comms from your K8s service YAML:

```
...
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges: 0.0.0.0/0
...
```